# Uncontrolled looping and function Skipping in C++?

Tags: c++, mbed

I am trying to read two user inputted numbers from a keypad onto a discovery board. I have the code working for reading the first number in but for some reason when it hits the same Keypad(); function for the second time it doesn't appear to be calling the function up to allow an input instead it skips over the scan and prints the lines under it and if you press the button to start over it is random where the program picks up, any ideas what could be causing this. I am compiling on mbeds online Ide. below is the code as well.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "mbed.h"
DigitalIn columns[3] = {PB_6, PB_7, PD_0};  // Columns for digital input

DigitalOut rows[4] = {PA_5, PA_1, PA_2, PA_3};  // rows for digital output

DigitalIn startButton(USER_BUTTON);

DigitalOut led1(LED1);  // reference LED
int numpad[4][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {-2, 0, -1}};  // keypad

int Total();
int Keypad();
int c = 0;
int Read;
int Num1 = 0;
int SelectOp();
int Oper;

int main() {
  while (1) {
    if (startButton == 1) {
      printf("%s\n\rInput First Number\n\r");
      wait(.5);
      Keypad();
      int First = Num1;
      Num1 = 0;

      printf("%s\n\r Your first number is ");
      printf("%i", First);
      printf("%s\n\r Input your second number\n\r");
      wait(.5);
      Keypad();  // this seems to be getting skipped
      int Second = Num1;
      Num1 = 0;

      printf("%s\n\r Your Second number is ");
      printf("%i", Second);

      printf("%s\n\rSelect Operator: 1(+), 2(-), 3(*), 4(/)");

      Keypad();

      Oper = Num1;
    }
  }
}

int Keypad() {
  columns[0].mode(PullUp);
  columns[1].mode(PullUp);
  columns[2].mode(PullUp);

  while (1) {
    if (Read == -1) {
      return Num1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      rows[0] = 1;
      rows[1] = 1;
      rows[2] = 1;
      rows[3] = 1;

      rows[i] = 0;
      wait(0.01);

      for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (columns[j] == 0) {
          Read = numpad[i][j];

          Total();

          c++;

          if (c == 5) {
            c = 0;
          }

          wait(0.005);
          while (columns[j] == 0)
            ;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int Total() {
  if (Read >= 0) {
    Num1 *= 10;
    Num1 += Read;
    printf("%i\n\r", Num1);

  } else {
    return Num1;
  }
  return Num1;
}
```

Comment: My guess (after eye-debugging): When you call `Keypad()` the 2nd time, this becomes effective immediately: `if (Read == -1) { return Num1; }`. That should teach you that **Global variables are evil.** (often). Instead, of `while (1) {` you could do `for (int Read = 0; Read >= 0;) {` (i.e. using a local variable) and move the `return Num;` after the loop. (And, think about what other global variable could be eliminated easily.)

Answer (score 1):

When `Read` is set to -1 during the first loop through Keypad(), it's still -1 when you enter `Keypad()` again, thus returning instantly.

Using some space to echo @Scheff on the importance of scoping variables according to their expected lifetimes and thus minimizing global variables wherever possible.